# How to connect mysql with nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I just started to learn nodejs with express framework.In my app there are two pages app.js and db.js..I need to post data from form and insert to register table
In db.js

```
 var mysql = require('./node_modules/mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'nodeapp'
        });
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
    });
    module.exports = connection;
```

// In my app.js page

```
  var express = require('./lib/express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var db = require('/db');
     app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile('/NodeProj/views/' + 'index.html');
    });
    /** bodyParser.urlencoded(options)
     * Parses the text as URL encoded data (which is how browsers tend to send form data from regular forms set to POST)
     * and exposes the resulting object (containing the keys and values) on req.body
     */
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    /**bodyParser.json(options)
     * Parses the text as JSON and exposes the resulting object on req.body.
     */
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.post('/process_form', function (req, res) {
        var response = {
            "firstname": req.body.fst_name,
            "email": req.body.fst_email,
            "password": req.body.fst_password
        };
        var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO register SET?',response,function(err,result){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result) console.log(result);
        });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    });

    app.listen(8081);
```

But when I run the code I got the following error

```
Refference error: connection is not defined
```

Please help me .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer [this](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/).....

Comment: Assuming the top bit of that code is the DB file, then your calling your MYSQL connection `db` when you require it in the app. If you change `var db = require('/db');` to `var connection = require('/db');` then that might help.

Comment: @PunitGajjar:But I need to define connection in db.js  and how access the page in app.js?

Comment: In addition to   @dan comment, it's `var connection = require('./db');`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you've called `connection` `db`.

So if you replace `var db = require('/db');` with `var connection = require('./db');` then your `connection` will be defined.

Comment: Thanks @baao. Updated the answer.